# Invalid conversion from void* to char* C++ reading linked list from File

Tags: c++, linked-list, getline

im trying to write a program that reads from a text file into a linked list

here is the list structure.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;


struct Video { 
char video_name[1024];      //  video name
int ranking;                // Number of viewer hits
char url[1024];             //  URL
Video *next;  // pointer to Video structure
}  *head = NULL;        // EMPTY linked list
```

here is the read-in code:

```
void load()
{
struct Video *temp;
temp = (Video*)malloc(sizeof(Video)); //allocate space for node 
temp = head;
ifstream rankFile ("Ranking.dbm");
if (rankFile.is_open())
{
    while ( rankFile.good() )
    {
        cin.getline(rankFile, temp->video_name, "\n");
        cin.getline(rankFile, temp->ranking, "\n");
        cin.getline(rankFile, temp->url, "\n");
        temp = temp->next; 

    }
    myfile.close();
}

else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

return ;

}
```

it is reading from a text file `Ranking.dbm` which looks like this:

```
bagheera
20
bagheera.com
sushi
60
sushi.com
wicket
99
wicket.com
teek
100
teek.com
```

however i am getting an error saying: `Invalid conversion from void* to char*` on all 3 of my `cin.getline()` statements while it is reading from the file. I need to be able to read in line by line from my file (`Ranking.dbm`) and store each set of 3 lines to `temp->video_name` , `temp->ranking` and `temp->url` and then create a new nodes and save the next 3 lines... so on and so forth till ive read in everything from the file.

how can i do this? am i going about this in a completely wrong manner or is this just a syntax error? i'm still getting the hang of C++ :/

Comment: This is C++? Looks like an odd mixin with C.

Comment: sorry yeah im trying to transfer an older C program to work in C++ and im still getting the hang of what I should and shouldnt use...

Comment: The character arrays are better replaced with `std::string`. `cin.getline` would then be replaced with `std::getline`. The nodes are better being smart pointers. C++ even has a linked list class - `std::list`.

Comment: On a side note, depending on where this code is going, in the long run you might find it more flexible to use a simple SQLITE db file instead of a homebrew text format to persist your data (it might save you a lot of 'rolling your own' data manipulation code).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect use of [`std::istream::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline):

```
cin.getline(rankFile, temp->video_name, "\n");
```

and does not make any sense as there are two input streams involved: `cin` and `rankFile`. The correct invocation (but not the most preferable) is:

```
rankFile.getline(temp->video_name, 1023);
```

Suggest:

- using [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of `char[]` and use [`std::getline(in, std::string&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).
- use `operator>>` to read the `int` as you cannot use `std::getline()` for this.
- check result of *every* read operation.
- don't use `malloc()` in C++ use `new` and `delete`.
- don't dynamically allocate if you don't have to.
- use one of the STL containers for holding a list rather than implementing that yourself, [`std::vector<Video>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for example.

For example:

```
struct Video { 
    std::string video_name;
    int ranking;
    std::string url;
};

std::vector<Video> load()
{
    std::vector<Video> result;
    std::ifstream rankFile("Ranking.dbm");
    if (rankFile.is_open())
    {
        Video temp;
        std::string line;
        while (std::getline(rankFile, temp.video_name) &&
               rankFile >> temp.ranking &&
               std::getline(rankFile, line) && // need to skip 'ranking's
                                               // unread new-line
               std::getline(rankFile, temp.url))
        {
            result.push_back(temp);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to open file"; 
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @CodingMash, it is unnecessary as the new-line character is the default. However, the type is `char` not `char*` so it should be `'\n'`.

Comment: so it looks like it work for `temp->video_name` and `temp->url` but when i tried to read in `rankFile.getline(temp->ranking, 1);` i get an error saying: `invalid conversion from int to char*`  should i be reading in the int differently?

Comment: @SunHypnotic, yes I mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
getline(rankFile, temp->video_name); // You should write it this way
```